# Cross domain authentification

Tags: authentication, security, web, browser, single-sign-on

#### Introduction

I am trying to implement cross domain authentication. The problem that I am currently facing relates to sharing the session between two domains.

Sadly, I cannot make changes to the architecture as the websites are old monoliths.

#### Current setup

Our current setup consists of the following:

1. A first web site that supports authentication. Let's call it `Site1.com`.
2. A REST API that manages the authentication.
3. A second website that `does not` support authentication. Lets call it `site2.com`.

[image]

Site1.com and the Authentication API reside under the same domain as shown in the diagram here above.

#### How the authentication works

The authentication is simple. site1.com submits credentials to auth.site1.com and on successful authentication, auth.site.com return a secure cookie.

[image]

#### The change

We would like to add authentication to `site2.com`. As the diagram below illustrates.

[image]

However, this has proven challenging as third party cookies have been disabled on Safari. Therefore the browser is not forwarding auth.site1.com cookies while the customer is on site2.com.

We ended up redirecting traffic using our gateway to overcome this problem. The gateway is presented by yellow circle in the diagram listed here below.

[image]

#### The current problem

Now the two websites support authentication. However, the cross domain authentication is not working. I cannot figure out how to implement this part properly. Any help will be really appreciated.

Analyzing how Google and YouTube cross domain authentication works has led me to the partial solutions listed here below. However, I cannot figure out how it performs Cross Domain SSO on the latest Safari browsers? Any indications will be really appreciated.

##### Partial solution 1:

Use the [SameParty attribute](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/first-party-sets-sameparty/) to declare my two websites as belonging to the same party and allow cookie sharing between this.

The solution will not need traffic redirection through the gateway. However, Safari and Firefox do not support it the cookie attribute.

##### Partial solution 2:

I have looked into performing Silent token acquisition using an iframe. Sadly, this solution does not work with recent safari browsers according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas):

> Silent token acquisition no longer works when third-party cookies are
> blocked - the application embedded in the iframe must switch to using
> popups to access the user's session as it can't navigate to the login
> page.

#### Other solutions

I have read on toolkit.org's blog about the [Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/). However, I am not sure if this will solve my problem. Also this solution might degrade the security.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing OAuth?

Comment: From my understanding, OAuth will not solve the problem as it uses third party cookies for cross domain authentication.